# How to implement critical sections on ARM Cortex A9

Tags: c, embedded, interrupts

I am porting some legacy code from an ARM926 core to CortexA9.  This code is baremetal and does not include an OS or standard libraries, all custom.  I am having a failure that appears to be related to a race condition that should be prevented by critical sectioning of the code.

I want some feedback on my approach to see if my critical sections may not be correctly implemented for this CPU. I am using GCC. I suspect there is some subtle error.

Also, is there an opensource library that has these types of primitives for ARM (or even a good lightweight spinlock/semephore library)?

```
#define ARM_INT_KEY_TYPE            unsigned int
#define ARM_INT_LOCK(key_)   \
asm volatile(\
    "mrs %[key], cpsr\n\t"\
    "orr r1, %[key], #0xC0\n\t"\
    "msr cpsr_c, r1\n\t" : [key]"=r"(key_) :: "r1", "cc" );

#define ARM_INT_UNLOCK(key_) asm volatile ("MSR cpsr_c,%0" : : "r" (key_))
```

The code is used as follows:

```
/* lock interrupts */
ARM_INT_KEY_TYPE key;
ARM_INT_LOCK(key);

<access registers, shared globals, etc...>

ARM_INT_UNLOCK(key);
```

The idea of the "key" is to allow nested critical sections, and these are used at the beginning and end of functions to create reentrant functions.

Thanks!

Comment: please reference to http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0008a/ch01s03s02.html don't do it in embedded asm btw. make it a function as the article does.

Comment: I know nothing about ARM, but I would expect that for mutex (or any cross-thread or cross-process sync function), you should be using the "memory" clobber to ensure that a) all memory values currently cached in registers get flushed back to memory *before* executing the asm and b) any values in memory that are accessed after the asm get re-loaded.  Note that performing a call (as HuStmpHrrr recommends) should implicitly perform this clobber for you.

Comment: Also, while I still don't speak ARM, your constraints for 'key_' doesn't look correct.  Since you say this is intended to be used for re-entry, declaring it as "=r" in the lock seems suspicious.  '=' means that you intend to overwrite it, and the existing value is unimportant.  It seems more likely you intended to use '+' to indicate your intention to update the existing value.  And again for unlock, listing it as an input tells gcc you don't intend to change it, but if I'm not mistaken, you do (change it).  I'm guessing this should also be listed as a '+' output.

Comment: +1 for coding in assembly for such a high spec core. Anyway, could this be related to privilege modes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will need to use `ldrex` and `strex` to do it properly.  Here's [a webpage](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344h/ch08s05s03.html) showing you how to use `ldrex` and `strex` to implement a spinlock.

Comment: Are you on a single core _solely_ wanting protection from preempting yourself? Otherwise, if you're trying to synchronise between multiple cores or DMA peripherals, then twiddling interrupts isn't going to work at all - you'll need the aforementioned exclusives _with proper barriers_ and a careful think about cache coherency.

Comment: The code looks fine. What makes you think out of the millions of code your ported those 4 lines are to blame?

Comment: Seems like the question is more suitable for SO, than for EE

Comment: Can you write test cases - for instance run low priority task that writes to a buffer, then start a higher priority one that interrupts it? Flip a pin somewhere when the contention takes place? Remove your critical section and watch things go south, then put it back in to fix the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most difficult part of handling a critical section without an OS is not actually creating the mutex, but rather figuring out what should happen if code wants to use a resource which is not presently available.  The load-exclusive and conditional-store-exclusive instructions make it fairly easy to create an "swap" function which, given a pointer to an integer, will atomically store a new value but return what the pointed-to integer had contained:

```
int32_t atomic_swap(int32_t *dest, int32_t new_value)
{
  int32_t old_value;
  do
  {
    old_value = __LDREXW(&dest);
  } while(__STREXW(new_value,&dest);
  return old_value;
}
```

Given a function like the above, one can easily enter a mutex via something like

```
if (atomic_swap(&mutex, 1)==0)
{
   ... do stuff in mutex ... ;
   mutex = 0; // Leave mutex
}
else
{ 
  ... couldn't get mutex...
}
```

In the absence of an OS, the main difficulty often lies with the "couldn't get mutex" code.  If an interrupt occurs when a mutex-guarded resource is busy, it may be necessary to have the interrupt-handling code set a flag and save some information to indicate what it wanted to do, and then have any main-like code which acquires the mutex check whenever it's going to release the mutex to see whether an interrupt wanted to do something while the mutex was held and, if so, perform the action on behalf of the interrupt.

Although it's possible to avoid problems with interrupts wanting to use mutex-guarded resources by simply disabling interrupts (and indeed, disabling interrupts can eliminate the need for any other kind of mutex), in general it's desirable to avoid disabling interrupts any longer than necessary.

A useful compromise can be to use a flag as described above, but have the main-line code which is going to release the mutex disable interrupts and check the aforementioned flag just before doing so (re-enable interrupts after releasing the mutex).  Such an approach doesn't require leaving interrupts disabled very long, but will guard against the possibility that if the main-line code tests the interrupt's flag after releasing the mutex, there's a danger that between the time it sees the flag and the time it acts upon it, it might get preempted by other code which acquires and releases the mutex and and acts upon the interrupt flag; if the main-line code doesn't test the interrupt's flag after releasing the mutex, an interrupt which occurs just before the main-line code releases the mutex might get blocked by the mutex but not noticed by the main-line.

In any case, what's most important will be to have a means by which code that tries to use a mutex-guarded resource when it's unavailable will have a means of repeating its attempt once the resource is released.

Answer (score 8):

This is a heavy handed way to do critical sections; disable interrupts.  It may not work if your system has/handles data faults.  It will also increase interrupt latency.  The [Linux irqflags.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/irqflags.h) has some macros that handle this.  The `cpsie` and `cpsid` instructions maybe useful; However, they do not save state and will not allow for nesting.  `cps` does not use a register.

For the *Cortex-A* series, the `ldrex/strex` are more efficient and can work to form a *mutex* for critical section or they can be used with *lock-free* algorithms to get rid of the critical section.

In some sense, the `ldrex/strex` seem like a ARMv5 `swp`.  However, they are much more complex to implement in practice.  You need a working cache and the target memory of the `ldrex/strex` needs to be in the cache.  The ARM documentation on the `ldrex/strex` is rather nebulous as they want mechanisms to work on non Cortex-A CPUs.  However, for the Cortex-A the mechanism to keep local CPU cache in sync with other CPUs is the same one used to implement the `ldrex/strex` instructions.  For the Cortex-A series the *reserve granual* (size of `ldrex/strex` reserved memory) is the same as a cache line; you also need to align memory to the cache line if you intend to modify multiple values, like with a doubly linked list.

> I suspect there is some subtle error.

```
mrs %[key], cpsr
orr r1, %[key], #0xC0  ; context switch here?
msr cpsr_c, r1
```

You need to ensure that the sequence can never be *pre-empted*.  Otherwise, you may get two *key* variables with interrupts enabled and the lock release will be incorrect.  You can use the `swp` instruction with the *key* memory to ensure consistency on the ARMv5, but this instruction is deprecated on the Cortex-A in favour of `ldrex/strex` as it works better for multi-CPU systems.

All of this depends on what kind of scheduling your system has.  It sounds like you only have mainlines and interrupts.  You often need the *critical section* primitives to have some hooks to the scheduler depending on what levels (system/user space/etc) you want the critical section to work with.

> Also, is there an opensource library that has these types of primitives for ARM (or even a good lightweight spinlock/semephore library)?

This is difficult to write in a portable way.  Ie, such libraries may exist for certain versions of ARM CPUs and for specific OSes.

Answer (score 3):

I see several potential problems with those critical sections. There are caveats and solutions to all of these, but as a summary:

- There's nothing preventing the compiler from moving code across these macros, for optimization or random other reasons.
- They save and restore some parts of the processor state the compiler expects inline assembly to leave alone (unless it's told otherwise).
- There's nothing preventing an interrupt from occurring in the middle of the sequence and changing the state between when it's read and when it's written.

First off, you definitely need some [compiler memory barriers](https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/). GCC implements these as [clobbers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers-and-Scratch-Registers). Basically, this is a way to tell the compiler "No, you can't move memory accesses across this piece of inline assembly because it might affect the result of the memory accesses." Specifically, you need both `"memory"` and `"cc"` clobbers, on both the begin and end macros. These will prevent other things (like function calls) from being reordered relative to the inline assembly too, because the compiler knows they might have memory accesses. I have seen GCC for ARM hold state in condition code registers across inline assembly with `"memory"` clobbers, so you definitely do need the `"cc"` clobber.

Secondly, these critical sections are saving and restoring a lot more than just whether interrupts are enabled. Specifically, they're saving and restoring most of the [CPSR (Current Program Status Register)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0363g/I2837.html) (the link is for Cortex-R4 because I couldn't find a nice diagram for an A9, but it should be identical). There are [subtle restrictions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0363g/I2837.html) around which pieces of state can actually be modified, but it's more than necessary here.

Among other things, this includes the condition codes (where the results of instructions like `cmp` are stored so subsequent conditional instructions can act on the result). The compiler will definitely be confused by this. This is easily solvable using the `"cc"` clobber as mentioned above. However, this will make code fail every time, so it doesn't sound like what you're seeing problems with. Somewhat of a ticking time bomb though, in that modifying random other code might cause the compiler to do something a little different which will be broken by this.

This will also attempt to save/restore the IT bits, which are used to [implement Thumb conditional execution](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0290g/Chdhiefi.html). Note that if you never execute Thumb code, this doesn't matter. I've never figured out how GCC's inline assembly deals with the IT bits, other than concluding it doesn't, meaning the compiler must never put inline assembly in an IT block and always expects the assembly to end outside of an IT block. I've never seen GCC generate code violating these assumptions, and I've done some fairly intricate inline assembly with heavy optimization, so I'm reasonably sure they hold. This means it probably won't actually attempt to change the IT bits, in which case everything is fine. Attempting to modify these bits is [classified as "architecturally unpredictable"](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0363g/I2837.html), so it could do all kinds of bad things, but probably won't do anything at all.

The last category of bits which will be saved/restored (besides the ones to actually disable interrupts) are the mode bits. These probably won't change, so it probably won't matter, but if you have any code that deliberately changes modes these interrupt sections could cause problems. Changing between privileged and user mode is the only case of doing this I would expect.

Third, there's nothing preventing an interrupt from changing other parts of CPSR between the `MRS` and `MSR` in `ARM_INT_LOCK`. Any such changes could be overwritten. In most reasonable systems, asynchronous interrupts don't change the state of the code they're interrupt (including CPSR). If they do, it becomes very hard to reason about what code will do. However, it is possible (changing the FIQ disable bit seems most likely to me), so you should consider if your system does this.

Here's how I would implement these in a way which addresses all the potential issues I pointed out:

```
#define ARM_INT_KEY_TYPE            unsigned int
#define ARM_INT_LOCK(key_)   \
asm volatile(\
    "mrs %[key], cpsr\n\t"\
    "ands %[key], %[key], #0xC0\n\t"\
    "cpsid if\n\t" : [key]"=r"(key_) :: "memory", "cc" );
#define ARM_INT_UNLOCK(key_) asm volatile (\
    "tst %[key], #0x40\n\t"\
    "beq 0f\n\t"\
    "cpsie f\n\t"\
    "0: tst %[key], #0x80\n\t"\
    "beq 1f\n\t"\
    "cpsie i\n\t"
    "1:\n\t" :: [key]"r" (key_) : "memory", "cc")
```

Make sure to compile with `-mcpu=cortex-a9` because at least some GCC versions (like mine) default to an older ARM CPU which doesn't support `cpsie` and `cpsid`.

I used `ands` instead of just `and` in `ARM_INT_LOCK` so it's a 16-bit instruction if this is used in Thumb code. The `"cc"` clobber is necessary anyways, so it's strictly a performance/code size benefit.

`0` and `1` are [local labels](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Local-Labels-1), for reference.

These should be usable in all the same ways as your versions. The `ARM_INT_LOCK` is just as fast/small as your original one. Unfortunately, I couldn't come up with a way to do `ARM_INT_UNLOCK` safely in anywhere near as few instructions.

If your system has constraints on when IRQs and FIQs are disabled, this could be simplified. For example, if they're always disabled together, you could combine into one `cbz` + `cpsie if` like this:

```
#define ARM_INT_UNLOCK(key_) asm volatile (\
    "cbz %[key], 0f\n\t"\
    "cpsie if\n\t"\
    "0:\n\t" :: [key]"r" (key_) : "memory", "cc")
```

Alternatively, if you don't care about FIQs at all then it's similar to just drop enabling/disabling them completely.

If you know that nothing else ever changes any of the other state bits in CPSR between the lock and unlock, then you could also use continue with something very similar to your original code, except with both `"memory"` and `"cc"` clobbers in both `ARM_INT_LOCK` and `ARM_INT_UNLOCK`

Answer (score 1):

for relatively simple critical sections, you can use LDREX and STREX instructions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795537/critical-sections-in-arm
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204f/Cihbghef.html

Answer (score 0):

You said,

> I am porting some legacy code from an ARM926 core to CortexA9.

The [SP7021](https://www.sunplus.com/products/SP7021.asp) is an interesting solution that you should consider if possible, because it contains 4 Arm7 cores, plus an ARM926 core, and an 8051 core as well. Not having to port that code would be a big win, and there's a reason why this chip was created with 4 cores for hosting Linux, but a completely separate core for the real-time aspect -- if you load down the real-time core with an OS, how can you ensure that your real-time code will not be compromised? This stuff is so hard to get right that I think the true solution is to find ways around it, like using separate chips. You also said,

> I suspect there is some subtle error.

As Jack Ganssle suggests in his book, ["The Art of Designing Embedded Systems"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750698691), chapter 3, "Stop Writing Big Programs", section "Partition with CPUs", pg. 41,

> "It's usually cheaper to add more CPUs merely for the sake of simplifying the software."

so please think of dedicating a core to the real-time aspect, like the SP7021 is built to do. (Full disclosure -- I have no relation to, or interest in, either the product or the company).

Here's a thought -- Just because your company is calling it "Legacy", just using that word automatically makes it seem old and crusty, and then of course we absolutely must replace it -- not necessarily! Debugged code is worth its weight in gold -- that's how much it cost to develop it, maintain it, upgrade it. And if a new microcontroller has the same "classic" core built inside it "just for real-time", then why shouldn't it be used?

What follows are my opinions on how I would like to see this type of code written, though I'm a Senior Developer who has not really done much of the real-time stuff (yet).

I like cooperative multitasking because it's predictable (which means it's *possible* to debug).

I like the coordination Language called [Linda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linda_(coordination_language)#Implementations), where work to be done gets posted, and worker processes "check out" a work item to work on it, then post the answer.

I do like the way [Erlang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)#Processes) does it (and I like their high availability):

> - Everything is a process.
> - Processes are strongly isolated.
> - Process creation and destruction is a lightweight operation.
> - Message passing is the only way for processes to interact.
> - Processes have unique names.
> - If you know the name of a process you can send it a message.
> - Processes share no resources.
> - Error handling is non-local.
> - Processes do what they are supposed to do or fail.

Instead of trying to handle locking and semaphores and race conditions and deadlocks, try adopting a solution where you don't actually need to act like you can actually do this stuff -- because nobody can -- not really. There's a reason why Linda and Erlang do it that way!

Comment: An 8051?? You should put a trigger warning on a post that suggests using an 8051 in this day and age. Good grief.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson -- I suppose next you'll have us remove all of the Cobol code, bringing the entire banking system to its knees.  ;-)  You're right, but he said that he has legacy code, and he might have some 8051 that he **also** has to rewrite.